# Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now cuando quiero pasar la consulta a procedimiento

Tags: php, mysqli

¡Hola! Lo que quiero hacer es cuando imprimo los registros en mi página, que solo me muestre 6 y que se cree un paginador, pero a la hora de ejecutar el archivo, tengo un error cuando llamo al procedimiento imprimir_pagina_principal() que es Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. ¿Cómo lo puedo arreglar? Lo curioso es que si pongo la consulta sin el procedure si anda! Pero me piden que sean con procedures...

Al principio del documento:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require_once("../admin/conexion.php");
$limite = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$limite = $limite * 6;
$contador = 0;
$seccion = 1;
$tipo = 1;

?>
```

Imprimo los resultados:

```
 try {
                
                $sql = "CALL imprimir_pagina_principal($seccion, $tipo, $limite)";
                $resultado = $conn->Query($sql);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

Y, por ultimo, el paginador:

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <?php 
            //echo $limite;
            $pag = 0;
            $query2 = "CALL buscar_contenido_pagina($seccion, $tipo)";
            $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)) {
              $pag++;
            }
            $pag = $pag / 6;
            $pag = ceil($pag);


          ?>

          <ul class="pagination">
            <?php
            $a = 0;
            for ($e = 1; $e < $pag + 1; $e++) {


            ?>

              <li><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="paig" href="?<?php echo $a; ?>"><?php echo $e; ?></a></li>
            <?php
              $a = $a + 1;
            }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Y los procedimientos:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS buscar_contenido_pagina //
CREATE PROCEDURE buscar_contenido_pagina (
    in _seccion INT,
    in _tipo INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT c.*, a.id_tipo_archivo FROM contenido c
    INNER JOIN archivo a ON c.id_archivo = a.id_archivo
    WHERE c.id_clasificacion = _seccion AND a.id_tipo_archivo = _tipo;


END//


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS imprimir_pagina_principal //
CREATE PROCEDURE imprimir_pagina_principal (
    in _seccion INT,
    in _tipo INT,
    in _limite INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT c.id_contenido, c.descripcion, c.autor, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_publicacion, '%d/%m/%y') AS fecha, c.titulo, c.portada, c.id_clasificacion, a.id_tipo_archivo, a.nombre 
    FROM contenido c
    INNER JOIN archivo a ON c.id_archivo = a.id_archivo
    WHERE c.id_clasificacion = _seccion AND a.id_tipo_archivo = _tipo 
    ORDER BY c.fecha_publicacion DESC 
    LIMIT 6 OFFSET _limite;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Este error se produce cuando se ejecuta un segundo comando de consulta (query) sin cerrar el comando anterior. Por ejemplo llamar a `imprimir_pagina_principal()` dentro de un loop de otra consulta. Puedes incluir el codigo o consultas que se hacen antes de esta llamada?

Answer (score 0):

Ahi lo arregle! Tenía que añadir esto:

```
 mysqli_free_result($resultado);
 mysqli_next_result($conn);
```